# What is the use of a variable in the class body?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

I understand that when we define a class variable in ruby it's preceded with 
`@@variableName` but in this code

```
class Hello
    @var2
    @@var3=0
    def foo1
        return @var1
    end
    def set_foo1(par1)
        @var1=par1
    end
end
```

I understand that var3 is a class variable and has to be initialized with some value. But what about var2? Is var2 still corresponds to an object?

When i called the program with  `obj1.var2=100` i get a **noMethodError**

Also, when i call puts `Hello.var3` i get the same **noMethodError**

Can anyone please explain where i am getting it wrong?

Comment: `@var2` is an instance variable, and `@@var3` is a class variable. If you want to access them from outside the scope of the class definition, you need getters/setters. *E.g.*, inside `class Hello`, `def var2 @var2 end`, etc.

Comment: So to access those variables we need to access them through a function only right?

Comment: Makes the PERFECT sense. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use, `obj.instance_variable_get(:@var2)`

Answer (score 2):

`@var2` is a class level instance variable, whereas `@@var3` is a class hierarchy variable.

An article about [usage and differences](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) between both of them. The important thing to remember: When you declare a class hierachy variable, it is shared between the class and all descending (inheriting) classes. This is rarely what you want.

Comment: Thanks. In a related Topic, it makes no sense to declare a variable with a single `@` inside the class methods right? (Because a class method can only access a class variable and so we define by a double @@)

Comment: Nope. Depending on the use case it might make perfectly sense to use a class level instance variable (for example for a global state). Whereas I can hardly think about a good example for a class hierarchy variable. I would argue that a class level instance variable is always preferred over a class hierarchy variable. And the later is almost everytime a bad decision.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are objects just like any other object. Objects can have instance variables. Ergo, classes can have instance variables.

There's really nothing special about that. That's very important to understand in Ruby.